# How to run an application in "background" or "hide" an application using apple script?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to start and hide quicktime player, start recording my iPhone screen for some duration and save the output on the desktop with file name "hello" with the below script

```
on run
    set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "hello.mov"
    set f to a reference to file filePath

    startVideoRecording(f)

end run

on startVideoRecording(f)

    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "h" using command down
        end tell
        set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
        set camera to "Prabhu Konchada's iPhone"
        tell newMovieRecording
            set camera to "Prabhu Konchada's iPhone"
            start
        end tell
        delay (10)
        pause
        save newMovieRecording in f
        stop
        close newMovieRecording
    end tell
end startVideoRecording
```

To hide quicktime player I tried :

1. tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player" to keystroke "h" using command down.
2. tell application "Finder"
   set visible of process "QuickTime Player" to false
   end tell
3. tell application "System Events"
   set frontProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
   set visible of frontProcess to false
   end tell

> The above 3 methods didn't serve my purpose and I don't want this quicktime all over my screen or visible in my DOCK ...

Answer (score 5):

```
tell application "System Events"
set visible of application process "QuickTime Player" to false
end tell
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

set the bounds of the front window to an "impossible" value and delete the `activate` line

```
on run
    set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "hello.mov"
    set f to a reference to file filePath

    startVideoRecording(f)

end run

on startVideoRecording(f)

    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        set newMovieRecording to new movie recording
        set bounds of window 1 to {-3000, 0, 100, 100}
        set camera to "Prabhu Konchada's iPhone"
        tell newMovieRecording
            set camera to "Prabhu Konchada's iPhone"
            start
        end tell
        delay (10)
        pause
        save newMovieRecording in f
        stop
        close newMovieRecording
    end tell
end startVideoRecording
```

Comment: yes, of course you need also the `on run` handler which I omitted in my post

Comment: could you edit your post as I tried with the on run handler

Comment: here we go. The movie is recorded and appears on the desktop after 10 seconds. Maybe the problem is the `camera` property, which not exists in QT Player dictionary. But there is a `current camera` property

Comment: how could you select the camera of the iPhone?

Comment: The camera property is fine and it did work for me. I did not want to have it all over my screen or in the dock. So wanted to run this in the background or hide the Application after it start's recording

Comment: using the camera property I did it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81708/discussion-between-vadian-and-prabhu-konchada).